# Receiving BLE packets without connection

Tags: c, esp32, nrf52

I'm working on a device (nrf52840) in my company that was developed but not till the end.
The device is a peripheral that collects data and advertises its packets using BLE5.
i want to make a device, esp32-s3, that receives the packets from the device via BLE5.
can i receive the packets without establishing a connection?
if so, what should i google to understand more?

plus if you have any more helpful tips it would be great.

unfortunately, i couldn't find helpful information.

Comment: You just perform a regular BLE scan.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the Generic Access Profile (GAP) structure, you can send and receive data up to 31 bytes of data without connecting to a device. This is also called advertising data.

If you want to exchange larger data, you can connect to the device with the Generic Attribute Profile (GATT) structure. You can send and receive data up to the maximum MTU size you have agreed with the device, ex(min 23 - ..... - max 512).